# appending or inserting an item to a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists, like

```
outlist = (['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], ['d4', 'd5', 'd6'])
```

I want to append ['d7', 'd8', 'd9'] to the above list

outlist.append(['d7', 'd8', 'd9']) gives me error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#42>", line 1, in <module>
    outlist.append(['d7','d8','d9'])
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

outlist.insert(['d7', 'd8', 'd9']) also gives me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    outlist.insert(['d7','d8','d9'])
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

Need help in resolving this. I would also want to write the 'outlist' to a csv file. How do I do that?

Comment: what you have is not a "list of lists", it's a "tuple" of lists. As the error suggests. So you need to use a list instead of a tuple if you want to append to it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a *tuple*, not a list, and those are immutable.

Use concatenation if you want to alter the tuple, adding another tuple with elements:

```
outlist += (['d7','d8','d9'],)
```

Here you re-bind `outlist` to a new tuple that is the concatenation of the original value plus a tuple of length one. You can omit the parenthesis even:

```
outlist += ['d7','d8','d9'],
```

as it is the comma that makes the expression on the right a tuple.

The alternative is to turn your tuple into a list with the `list()` type *first*:

```
outlist = list(outlist)
```

and now you can call `.append()` and `.insert()` at will.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute ...
> ```

That is **not** a list, that is a [**tuple**](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). Tuples are immutable, therefore there is no way to do what you want. Convert it to a mutable sequence first.

```
outlist = list(outlist)
```

Or create it as a list in the first place.

(And next time, spend a few moments *reading* the error message first.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a list of lists, it's a tuple containing two lists. Tuples are immutable in Python.
Change the first line to:

```
outlist = [['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], ['d4', 'd5', 'd6']]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Tuples](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) are immutable in Python. Convert `outlist` to `list` if you want to add an item:

```
>>> outlist = (['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], ['d4', 'd5', 'd6'])
>>> outlist = list(outlist)
>>> outlist.append(['d7', 'd8', 'd9'])
>>> outlist
[['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], ['d4', 'd5', 'd6'], ['d7', 'd8', 'd9']]
```